# How to ask someone when they will submit their work in an e-mail

Tags: grammaticality, british-english, email, formal-language

In brief, I want to write an e-mail inquiring an agency as when will they submit the work.
This is what I have written. I am not quiet sure whether it is the proper way of writing the mail. I would appreciate if you could provide feedback as to how can I write it in correct grammar.

> Dear Xyz,
>
> Hope you had a great weekend. I wish to inquire as when will you submit the files regarding the project.
>
> Many thanks,
>   Oklao Sds

Is it grammatically acceptable?

Comment: "I hope you had a great weekend. I wish to inquire when you submit the files regarding the project," seems better.

Comment: @Carlo_R, no, you need an auxiliary verb there: I wish to inquire when you ***will*** submit

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Its pretty close.

> **I hope** you had a great weekend. I wish to inquire **as to** when **you will** submit the files regarding the project.

"Hope" by itself is a bit too informal for a business situation.
"as to" is basically the same as "regarding".
"you will" since this clause is not a question. If it were, you could use "will you".

Comment: Unless you use British English - then it's "enquire".